# Adsense and SSL? Still an issue?

Tags: google, https, google-adsense

I just switched over to SSL for my site using cloudflare's flexible SSL, but forcing https via page rules, and pointing all internal links to https. I also added the https version of the aite to WMT. My Q is this: I freaked after learning many people have had adsense revenue drop after making the switch as only secure ads are served. After quickly switching back to http i took a leap of faith and decided to move forward with https and see how it goes.  Is a decrease in revenue still an issue with adsense on SSL sites or is it neglible? My site doesnt cover much sensitive information for now but we will be inteoducing a login and account panel soon. I mainly switched because it makes the site look more credible and I wanted that potential ranking boost, however small it os, but do not want to compromise revenue. Would love to hear your opinions.

Regards

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98335/effect-of-choosing-https-over-http-in-a-new-website-for-adsense-seo/98339#98339

Comment: Well, that was a useful post and scared me into disabling ssl immediately lol. But seriously, I think it may be a good move down the road if implemented correctly. I am just simultaneously working on a website redesign and do not want things to get messy. lol

Comment: I getcha! It is a disruption. But not too bad considering any benefit you may get. Personally, if anyone wants to be private looking at any website I create, there is something seriously wrong with them. ;-) It is a good thing for trust. But I am kinda protesting Google pushing it's agenda onto the Internet yet again. Now there is a backlash and Google will not win the *everyone must use HTTPS for privacy* policy war.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to HTTPS about two weeks ago and have not noticed a change as of yet. I'm praying that my Adsense revenue does not change drastically. However, according to Google it should not change.

Here's an excerpt from Google:

> HTTPS-enabled sites require that all content on the page, including the ads, be SSL-compliant. For most users, AdSense ad requests are always SSL-compliant and always served over HTTPS, even when the surrounding site is HTTP. The same ads compete in the auction, so switching your site to HTTPS will have no effect on the ads most users see, or on auction pressure. The only exception is for users located in countries that block or otherwise degrade HTTPS traffic.